# Do I need to use the article if I skip the noun in a sentence with an adjective and "or"?

Tags: grammar, articles, adjectives

For example:

Would you like a smoking or non-smoking table?

Would you like a smoking or a non-smoking table?

Comment: you might want to reread your question.

Comment: I'd put the article in, but I probably wouldn't even notice if somebody left it out.

Comment: No, you don't need it. It can be elided